# ClosedXML can't delete file after saving Workbook "process in use"

Tags: runtime-error, delete-file, closedxml, file-processing

So here's the code:

```
                string filename = @"c:\test.xlsx";
                using (XLWorkbook wb = CreateWorkbookInformation())
                {
                    wb.SaveAs(filename);
                    Email.EmailAsAttachment(filename);
                }

                File.Delete(filename);
```

It creates the Workbook information just fine, it saves the file fine, it emails the file fine as an attachment... However, when I try to delete file (after the `using` statement), it states the "process is in use".  There shouldn't be anything keeping the file open?!?  What process am I missing that I should close in order to delete the file?

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, nevermind, had nothing to do with ClosedXML, had everything to do with attaching the file to the email and not using a proper `using`statement for the attachment.  So the attachment process was keeping the file open.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for posting this answer!!!
I went crazy trying to understand what's my problem!
I did as you suggested and  used  the proper `using` statement:

```
            using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(senderAdress, emailAdress))
            {
                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
                client.Port = 25;
                client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                client.Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPHostName"];
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(client.Host))
                {
                    errorMsg = "ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[\"SMTPHostName\"] not found";
                    return false;

                }

                mail.Subject = subject;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = isBodyHtml;
                mail.Body = body;

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(attachmentFullPath))
                {
                    if (File.Exists(attachmentFullPath))
                    {
                        System.Net.Mime.ContentType contentType = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType();
                        contentType.MediaType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet;
                        contentType.Name = Path.GetFileName(attachmentFullPath);
                        mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(attachmentFullPath, contentType));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        errorMsg = "Attachment File Doesn't Exist: " + attachmentFullPath;
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                client.Send(mail);

            }
```